# Tikz positionning on the baseline

Tags: positioning, nodes, baseline

I have the following piece of code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[mainbullet/.style={rectangle, minimum size=0.3cm,draw=orange!100, fill=orange!100,thick}, %
maintitle/.style={rectangle,opacity= 0.5}, %
date/.style={black, opacity=0.5}]
\tikz[baseline=(experiencetitle.base)]{%
\node[mainbullet] (experiencebullet) at (0,-23) {}; %
\node[maintitle](experiencetitle)[right =10mm of experiencebullet]{Experience};
\node(experiencedesc1)[below= 5mm of experiencetitle] {Experience};
\node[date](date1)[left=15mm of experiencedesc1]{1999-2000};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like the `experiencetitle` and the `experiencebullet` to be aligned on their baseline. The code shown hereabove seems to align them based on the rectangle center (the `experiencebullet` node) rather than its baseline and I do not understand why.

Could someone give me a hint about where I am mistaking ?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and the link. I'll make that in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [mainbullet/.style={rectangle, minimum size=0.3cm, draw=orange!100, fill=orange!100, thick},
    maintitle/.style={rectangle, opacity=0.5}]
    \node[mainbullet] (experiencebullet) at (0, -23) {};
    \node[maintitle] (experiencetitle) [right=10mm of experiencebullet.south east, anchor=base west] {Experience};

    \draw (experiencebullet.south east) -- +(10mm, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]